# Unable to find element with id == bla bla (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver

I'm using IE8, Selenium WD 2.33.0,XP

My Code:

```java
File file = new File("D:/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", IEDriver.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities c=DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
c.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

WebDriver d=new InternetExplorerDriver(c);
d.get(URL);
d.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

d.findElement(By.id("Logon:LogonScreen:username")).sendKeys("admin");
Thread.sleep(3000);

d.findElement(By.id("Logon:LogonScreen:password")).sendKeys("admin");
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.id("Logon:LogonScreen:button")).submit();
```

> Error: Unable to find element with id == Logon:LogonScreen:username (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I have located Element by name/abs xpath/rel xpath/ cssbt: not working. I have done all the Setting changes such as: 'Tools -> Internet options -> Connections -> LAN settings -> un check Automatic configurations.' and checked all the security settings.

I will share my HTML source code soon.

Till then please help. I saw that you were also facing the same problem and you were able to solve it.

Regards.

Comment: Sharing the html would do lot of good. The sooner the better.

Comment: Remove this to begin with: `c.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following code.

d.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
Thread.sleep(3000);

d.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin");
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.id("button")).submit();

I guess the driver was unable to recognize the sequence that has been given to find the element.

HTH,
Sham_